# Attribute Error : 'Request' object has no attribute 'headers'- Django

Tags: react-native, django-rest-framework

I am using the django 1.11 version and django rest framework for the rest api
I am passing the token value in the HTTP header in React Native using fetch

But when I am trying to retrieve the token value in django views file it is giving me error

In react Native I am passing the token value as below

```
fetch(url,{
  method: 'get',
  headers : new Headers({
    'token':'token',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'

  })
})
```

I django rest APi I am trying to fetch the token value as below

```
 def get(self,request,**kwargs):
        token = request.headers['token']
        queryset=models.Schedule.objects.filter()
        serializer_class= RepScheduleSerializer(queryset,many=True)
        return Response(serializer_class.data)
```

But it is giving me error 
Request object has no attribute headers

I want to fetch the token value in the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The headers of a request are stored in the [**`request.META`** dictionary [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META). You thus should alter the code to:

```
def get(self,request,**kwargs):
        token = request.META['HTTP_TOKEN']
        queryset = models.Schedule.objects.all()
        serializer_class = RepScheduleSerializer(queryset,many=True)
        return Response(serializer_class.data)
```

Right now however, you do not do anything with this token. You thus might need to alter the logic.

Note that the keys are pre-processed:

> With the exception of `CONTENT_LENGTH` and `CONTENT_TYPE`, as given above, **any HTTP headers in the request are converted to `META` keys by converting all characters to uppercase, replacing any hyphens with underscores and adding an `HTTP_` prefix** to the name. So, for example, a header called `X-Bender` would be mapped to the META key `HTTP_X_BENDER`.

Since [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), there is the [**`request.headers`** dictionary-like object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.headers), that allows case-insensitive lookups. Based on the error message, you however do not use [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2).

Comment: This didnt worked Its giving me error key error u'token' when I print the request.META value there is no token key

Comment: @Nidhi: are you sure the request is triggered by the ract-native request, and not by another request?

Comment: @Nidhi: hold on, the tokens are written in uppercase at the server side.

Comment: @Nidhi: you  probably should look for `HTTP_TOKEN`.

Comment: Yup I got the value its was on HTTP_TOKEN Thanks for the help